AppData/Roaming. Moving. Error. "More than 256 characters long" filenames
What am I trying to do?
I am changing 'Location' of the AppData/Roaming folder to another partition of the same disk, as shown on the screenshot below.

The screenshot shows in blue background the destination address for the destination folder. The window is "Roaming Properties" and the selected tab is "Location".
AppData takes up too much space and my "Windows 10" partition is almost out of space, as shown on the screenshot below.

The screenshot shows "Devices and units".
What is happening instead?
I am instead getting the error shown on the screenshot below.

It has the title: 'The folder can't be moved here', and continues by saying:

'Failed to copy files from X to Y . This can happen when one or more
files in the origin or destiny folders have a filename longer than 256
characters.
The operation was cancelled by the user.'

What have I already tried to do?

Could not find an answer on SuperUser;
I tried to change LongPathsEnabled to 1, but it was already 1;
What I noticed, doing my own experiments, is that the AppData/Roaming/Microsoft subfolder cannot be renamed, deleted or moved, and that it may be the cause of the error. I cannot do anything with it even when using an elevated cmd. So it may be blocking the setting of the new address for the AppData/Roaming folder.

Question:
How to solve the 256 characters error, in order to adequately move the AppData/Roaming folder?

So is the path of X or Y larger than 256 characters?  All screenshots should be in English or an English translation should be provided

@Ramhound The paths of X and Y are not longer than 256 characters, but I don't know the path extension of subfolders and files inside the subfolders. Is there a quick way to find out, without checking file-by-file by hand?

@Ramhound I added more information in English for describing each screenshot, as requested.

Beware that the message says "This can happen ...", meaning that it's not sure that's the actual cause. I've seen (and coded) such messages

Also, frame challenge: Do you really need 3 separate partitions, causing you to maneuver content between them? Presumably this is a single ~250GB drive, so consider re-partitioning it to a single ~250GB partition

I agree with @Jonathan. This feels a bit like an XY problem. You're asking about moving the roaming folder, but the actual problem you're trying to solve is not enough space on  your C: partition. The obvious solution would be to just merge your partitions.

@Jonathan I'm aware of the uncertainity the error messages allows. What I noticed, doing my own experiments, is that the AppData/Roaming/Microsoft folder cannot be renamed, deleted or moved, and that it may be the cause of the error. I cannot do anything with it even when using an elevated cmd. So it may be blocking the setting of the new address for the Roaming folder. But that, of course, makes no sense: why would Microsoft allow me to change the location of the folder and at the same time own a Microsoft subfolder that blocks the process?

@Dnomyar96 I believe that I would have other benefits if I could move AppData out of the C: partition. I'm on a Active Directory domain that syncs the user folders through a server and unfortunately, the login process is very very slow due to the amount of data being synced. I already moved all user files to the E: partition and would like to have AppData on the D: partition in order to have a very slim user folder to be synced.

@BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah: If you do manage to move ....\AppData\Roaming through the screenshotted UI, the system will use that as appdata (technically the APPDATA env variable and the corresponding shell folder), so domain sync would still include them. If you want to avoid that, then you need to config the heavier apps to save their stuff elsewhere (like a different answer suggests with e.g. Thunderbird). This is unrelated to whether that's on the C: partition or not.

@BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah - Why don’t you know? It’s your path to your file? %AppData% most certainly can be moved to another location.

@Ramhound Why don't I know what?

@BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah - "I don't know the path extension of subfolders and files inside the subfolders." - You tell me what you don't know because I don't understand why you don't know what is in your own profile's folders.

@Ramhound It is not feasible to access every subfolder and count the filepath length of every file inside them. That's what I meant.

Generally, it is not a good idea to change Windows System folder locations, though it can be done. If some particular application is making AppData too large, try relocating just that app.
Use a tool such as WinDirStat or alternative to analyze the folder and subfolders and find the culprits consuming drive space, and move that app's data.
As an example, the Thunderbird email client profile in AppData/Roaming may be hundreds of megabytes, or even some gigabytes. It can easily be moved elsewhere using its Profile Manager.

"Microsoft" folder takes up 44.4% of the "AppData/Roaming" space, followed by "Mozilla", that takes 26.4% of the space. I know that I can move my Mozilla Firefox profile, but how about the Microsoft folder?

Look for items in AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/ that can be moved out. What takes up so much room? On this PC, there's ~130 MB in that folder, and ~120 MB are my own files in C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu, which I chose to put there, but just as easily move elsewhere.

It's the Teams subfolder.

are you currently logged in as the user whose profile directories you are modifying?

You can clear the Teams cache: https://www.easytweaks.com/teams-clear-remove-cache-location/ , which should free up some space without moving it. You could make a batch file with that command, and run it manually or as a scheduled task.

@BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah - Only %AppData% needs to be referenced, and I argue doesn’t actually have to be, for either of those folders to exist and be discoverable. LongPathsEnabled doesn’t apply to File Explorer (it never has).

@Ramhound Sorry, I did not understand anything you said on your last comment. Which relationship what you said has with the answer provided?

So warnings aside (yes this is a bad idea, in particular for %appdata%, since it's virtually mapped) there are a couple approaches to deal with the 256-character path limitation.
The first and most applicable to you, is to perform a recursive copy with robocopy. Robocopy is a sophisticated application designed to provide "Robust Copy" functionality, similar to the kinds of features you'd see in Linux's rsync. it will take a bit of work to find the exact set of options you need, but robocopy does not by default limit file operations to objects with a path of less than 256 characters (unless you use the /256 switch).
Another more old-school approach that you can use with almost any copy application is to use the subst command to shorten the path. for instance the command subst b: c:\users\UserName\AppData\Roaming will map the roaming dir to the drive label b:, so when you copy from b:, the path is ~30 characters shorter.

About the robocopy suggestion: I'm totally able to copy the entire AppData/Roaming folder using FIle Explorer. The problem is that the Microsoft folder cannot be deleted or renamed, so I cannot get rid of it to clear the AppData/Roaming space entirely, and as such, be entirely sure that the new location is being used in full. So, setting the new location in the "Location" tab of the "Roaming Properties" gives me an error when I choose to move files, or doesn't guarantees anything when I don't set to move.
